# Image thumbnail in a WinForms listbox

Tags: c#, winforms, image, listbox

I am trying to display a thumbnail inside a listbox in a Windows Form application.  I've read around and seen all sorts of suggestions, but I'm looking for the simplest one.  Here's the details of what I'm trying to do.

I am trying to display a thumbnail of an image AND display text next to it.

I've looked at ListViews and they don't seem to offer what I am looking for.  Any code would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

set your listbox to ownerdraw

then in the itemdraw event (or is it drawitem?)  grab your image and draw it in the space allotted  (`e.Graphics.DrawImage`), then draw the test of the item next to it (`e.Graphics.DrawString`)

Comment: This is the correct approach, but you'll also have to handle drawing the item when it's in various states (selected, highlighted, etc.)

Comment: Thanks, Ed, for the additional detail.  Very helpful.

Comment: I'f you want this to be reusable, you'll also have to handle resizing of the image, by either cropping, compressing or stretching the image to the correct size.  Alternatively you could change the size of an item to fit the image.  I suggest you override the ListBox class and add this with properties to customize the required behavior.

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of implementations of an ImageListBox. One can be found here: 
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/combobox/imagelistbox.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Assign an image list to the ListBox and set the View property to: List or Tile, now for each item choose which image from the list should be displayed. Looks exactly like ListBox with images to me ;)

Comment: This would be a ListView rather than a ListBox.

Comment: the principle is there but Tim is right ... the ListView will do this