# How can i draw an image in the listbox along with the listboxItem [c# winforms]

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox, listboxitem, drawimage

(I'm working in winforms using c#)
I have a Listbox ,with some items added to it.My problem is i want to draw an image in the left side of each and every items in the listbox.Can anyone suggest any idea?
Thanks in advance.

I can do this by using ImageList.

```
imageList.Draw(ea.Graphics, bounds.Left, bounds.Top,item.ImageIndex);
```

but i want to use like this

```
ea.Graphics.DrawImage("someImage",new point);
```

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/875288/image-thumbnail-in-a-winforms-listbox. The maiun idea that you need to redraw the item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a listview control not a listbox for this. The listview natively supports imagelist binding and listviewitem has imageindex property so that you can specify the index of the image to render from the imagelist.

Comment: but i don't want to use a ImageList

Comment: However... i am convinced it is easier to handle item ownerdrawing and customize your rendering in a listview which already spaces and aligns item text and picture rather than doing all the alignment in a listbox. your call, you decide :-)

Answer (score 0):

Probable approach -

You can have "List item" composed of UI control with image or drawing area (depends on your requirement). This way you should be able to draw.

Check this project from [code project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/list/EXListView.aspx)